# Exporting a game, but game isn't exporting everything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, build, exe

I am very new to Unity, and just created my first game. The problem is that some of the code isn't working. My enemies are supposed to follow and kill my player after 60 seconds, but when I run the game after using Inno Setup, the enemies spawn, and just stand still. I tried going into the folders and using the raw exe file, when it was just built, and nothing changed, I tried adding more logic too my game by using bool's, that didn't help. This works in Unity just not outside of it.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class EneAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject player;   
    private Rigidbody eneRB;

    public static float _speed = 2;

    public static bool playerDead = false;
    void Start()
    {
        eneRB = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 eneLook = (player.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position).normalized;
        eneRB.AddForce(eneLook * _speed);        
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coli)
    {
        if(coli.gameObject.name == "3dPOV")
        {
            Destroy(coli.gameObject);
            playerDead = true;
            if(playerDead == true)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("StartMenu");
                playerDead = false;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

This script makes it so that the enemy can attack the player. And controls the pplayer dead bool, so if the player dies it goes back to the start menu (It doesn't work, if you can tell me how to fix it thanks)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{       
    public GameObject enemy;
    [SerializeField]
    public Vector3 spawnCords;
    private Quaternion eneRota;    

    private int eneSpawnCount = 10;

    public static bool eneSpawned = false;

    void Start()
    {        
        StartCoroutine(spawnTime());
    }

    public IEnumerator spawnTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(60f);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < eneSpawnCount; i++)
            {
                Vector3 enePos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnCords.x, spawnCords.x), spawnCords.y, Random.Range(-spawnCords.z, spawnCords.z));
                eneRota = Quaternion.identity;
                Instantiate(enemy, enePos, eneRota);
            }
            eneSpawned = true;
        }
        StartCoroutine(speedIncrement());
    }

    public IEnumerator speedIncrement()
    {
        if(eneSpawned == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(15f);
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                EneAttack._speed += 0.25f;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(30f);
            }
        }

        if(EneAttack._speed < 2.75f)
        {
            EneAttack._speed = 2.75f;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the spawning script for the enemies

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController control;
    public Transform cam;
    public Vector3 playerScale;    
    public GameObject player;   

    public int speed = 4;

    public float smoothSpeed = 0.1f;
    float turnSmoVelo;

    public bool powerUpTrue = false;
    public bool powerDone = false;
    public bool powerUpDone = false;

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);

        if(direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float tarAng = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, tarAng, ref turnSmoVelo, smoothSpeed);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, tarAng, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            control.Move(moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }        
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;              
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Speed"))
        {
            speed += 1;
            if(speed == 5 && powerDone == false)
            {
                speed -= 4;
                powerDone = true;
            }
            if(speed > 10)
            {
                speed = 10;
            }
            if(powerUpDone == true)
            {
                powerDone = true;
            }
            powerUpTrue = true;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);                        
        }

        if(other.CompareTag("Scaling"))
        {
            {
                playerScale += new Vector3(0.025f, 0.00025f, 0.025f);
                player.transform.localScale += playerScale;
                control.radius -= 0.05f;
                if(control.radius <= 0)
                {
                    control.radius = 0;
                }
            }
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            powerUpTrue = true;
        }

        if(other.CompareTag("FSpeed"))
        {
            powerUpDone = true;
            speed -= 1;
            if(speed <= 0)
            {
                speed += 1;
            }
            if(speed == 4 && powerUpDone == true)
            {
                speed = 1;
            }
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }

        if(other.CompareTag("FScale"))
        {
            {
                playerScale += new Vector3(0.025f, 0.00025f, 0.025f);
                player.transform.localScale -= playerScale;
                control.radius += 0.05f;
            }
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }    
}
```

This makes it so the player can move and controls the powerup's, but those work just fine.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Start Menu script, like I said above, if anyone can help me on when the player dies, it brings you to the start menu

If you need anymore information, let me know.

Comment: @jps okay let me change it, one second

Comment: @jps Changed it from picture's to code